# Should I close Streams created with java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream?

Tags: java, stream, nio2

In the stream tutorial, nothing is said about closing streams gained from `Files.newInputStream( path )`. Only some obscure:

> Whether the returned stream is asynchronously closeable and/or
>   interruptible is highly file system provider specific and therefore
>   not specified.

What is "asyncronously" in this context? If I close the stream explicitly or if another thread closes the stream asyncronously?

Comment: Left unclosed, it seems to keep a file descriptor occupied per file provided by the stream... which is really not what you may want dealing with large directories.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You definitely must close the obtained `InputStream`, just like all others. The term "asynchronously closeable" refers to the ability to close the stream while another thread is blocked on an I/O operation on it.

From [`InterruptibleChannel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/InterruptibleChannel.html) documentation:

> A channel that implements this interface is *asynchronously closeable*: If a thread is blocked in an I/O operation on an interruptible channel then another thread may invoke the channel's close method. This will cause the blocked thread to receive an AsynchronousCloseException.

Comment: So the authors of the tutorial just forgot about closing the streams? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html#textfiles

Comment: No. They use the proper Automatic Resource Management idiom.

Comment: That is what I want to know, what is this Idiom where is it described? Is the destructor closing the stream? I seem to have overlooked an essential part.

Comment: Found it, here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/trywithresources-401775.html Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this conveniently with the new try with resources option.

```
try(/*initialize resources here*/)
{
}
```

They will automatically be closed after the try block.  Add a catch as necessary.